# Looking for a batch file that will give me file dimensions in a folder of jpgs

Tags: image, batch-file, dimensions, image-size

I'm trying to find a batch file that I can run in a folder of jpgs that will give me either pixel dimensions or height and width in inches along with the file names... anything like that already out there? thx.

Comment: There is no way using just batch-file commands to extract the dimensions from a JPG file.  However, you may be able to find a utility that will do that, or perhaps something in PowerShell?  Your questions seems more suited to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is a hybrid batch/jscript file that can be used as a base for your code. Save as batch file. When executed, it will return the dimensions of the files that expose a dimension property in the indicated folder.

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off

    Cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0" /folder:"%~dp0" /delim:";"

    exit /b

@end
var DETAILS_FILENAME=0;
var DETAILS_DIMENSIONS=31;

    var folder=WScript.CreateObject('Shell.Application').NameSpace(WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('folder'));
    var delim=WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists('delim') ? WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('delim') : '|';
    for (var e=new Enumerator(folder.Items()); !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()){
        var i=e.item(); 
        var d=folder.GetDetailsOf(e.item(),DETAILS_DIMENSIONS); 
        if (d) WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(folder.GetDetailsOf(i,DETAILS_FILENAME) + delim + d.replace(/[^0-9x]*/g,''));
    };
```